# How to know the number of argument passed to a shell script minus one?

Tags: scripts

I would like to know how to indicate the number of arguments passed to a shell script minus 1. I tried like this: ${#-1} but it does not work. Could anyone help me please? thank you for answering.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [arithmetic expansion syntax](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/arith) to perform calculations with variables, and get the number of arguments for your script or current function from `$#`:

```
count_minus_one=$(( $# - 1 ))

echo "$count_minus_one"
```

It might be preferable to assign the number of all arguments to a custom variable first, which is especially needed if you want the length of an arbitrary array instead of the script/function argument count, because you can't do proper variable expansion in arithmetic expansions. That would look like:

```
all_count=$#
count_minus_one=$(( all_count - 1 ))

echo "$count_minus_one"
```